# Trying to understand timezones in Java

Tags: java, date, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a very simple Java program as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET));
    cal.set(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET, 0);
    System.out.println(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
}
```

My home timezone is GMT. For the purpose of my experiment I set the computer's timezone to EDT and observed the system clock has moved back 5 hours.

When I run the program, I get this output:

```
Sat Apr 25 10:09:23 EDT 2015
-18000000
Sat Apr 25 05:09:23 EDT 2015
```

The `Sat Apr 25 10:09:23 EDT 2015` indicates the system time and timezone, as expected.

The `-18000000` indicates the zone offset in ms, which is negative 5 hours as expected.

When I set the zone offset to 0, I would expect the time to read my real local time of 15:09 but instead it reads 05:09, in other words, it has taken off another 5 hours instead of adding them.

Why? I'm confused!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have done is set a calendar with the current time  in the current timezone (-5 hours) (10:09) you then got the time in Milliseconds which returns the milliseconds time as if you are in GMT. Ie It adds 5 hours (15:09)

System.out.println(New Date(milliseconds)) interprets that time in the current timezone (-5 hours)(10:09)

You then change the zone offset to zero but keep the day and time numbers unchanged. (10:09) You then take time in Milliseconds again which again is as if it is GMT (it adds nothing) (10:09)

System.out.println(New Date(time in millis)) interprets that time in the current timezone (-5 hours) (05:09)

The key information here is that a Date is always GMT internally and the timezone is only applied when you format it or call toString() which is done by the println (...) method.

calendar.getTimeInMillis () always returns the number of milliseconds since the start of 01/01/1970 UTC (the computer epoch)

Answer (score 0):

Java takes your computer's timezone which is EDT. When you set the Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET to '0' then it will give you the current EDT time. If you need to get your current time you need to set the Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET related to EDT which is 5 hours (+18000000ms).

**[UPDATE]** 
Time zone offset set to '0' means declaring I am at GMT and system time is GMT. 
But you need to keep in mind that still you are in your original location which is -18000000.
When you calculate you take the correct location which is -1800000 and then adjust 5 hours early time.

Let me explain what you did using an example.

Think you can go to any location of the world in no time.
You set your time at New York (EST) to 10:00.
Now you go to Greenwich (GMT) and you are saying that my time is 10:00. (setting the time zone offset to '0') 
Then you come to New York (EST) and print your time thinking that 10:00 is the time at Greenwich (GMT) which is 05:00.

Comment: but EDT has an offset of -5 hours, and this was correctly reported. GMT has on offset of zero. This still does not make sense.